# Cannot remove index.php from urls using Codeigniter on MAC OSX

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mamp

I just bought a Mac-pro with Mavericks 10.9.1 and before that I was working on pc with Windows 7.

I created a project under the windows 7 OS and now I want to import it to OSX, the import was successful apart from the .htaccess file. I can't remove `index.php` from my urls.
I have MAMP installed and my urls only work if I use `index.php`:

- don't work : `(localhost/~username/feel/products)`
- work : `(localhost/~username/feel/index.php/products)`

I tried all the options of RewriteEngine, RewriteCond and RewriteRule in .htaccess file.
I give all the folders/files chmod 755, have put `$config['base_url']=''` and `$config['index_page'] = '';` with and without root or index.php page.

The file .htaccess is in the same folder of the index.php page, the AllowOverride None is AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is related to the way OS X handles different users for apache. I used the .htaccess file as described in the [CodeIgniter URL documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) and added a line using RewriteBase.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/path/to/CI/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

By the way, I'm using OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks) and CodeIgniter 2.2.0

Comment: This did it for me! Also modified httpd.conf as per @stomdrain. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `AllowOverride All` in the `Directory`:

`/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
182 <Directory />
183     Options +FollowSymLinks
184     AllowOverride All
185     Order deny,allow
186     Deny from all
187 </Directory>
```

then restart Apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```