# Fix `index.php` Codeigniter 3.x - Mac OS - Xampp

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I recently shifted from Windows to MAC (Catalina 10.15.4). I installed Xampp and clone my Codeigniter project into /htdocs. I want to fix index.php issue **"Remove index.php from url"**, which most of you guys are familiar with. Can anyone know how to fix this in MAC ?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Rsss';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit. Sounds like your mod-rewrite is not enabled

Comment: Are you now using PHP-FPM now you moved to the MAC?

Comment: Brother thanks for reaching out. I tried this. But it didn't work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope.

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255653/2275490

Comment: @Vickel I have already tried this. The point is Xampp his its own apache. Rewriting /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf does not make any sense. I have applied all the required settings to Xampp's apache but it's not working.

Comment: @NilankaManoj Thanks for reaching out. Already tried this.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks bro. Your mentioned link help me in someway. And now i'm using system's default apache & getting rid of xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. It's a proper solution but not for XAMPP users.
Edit your `/httpd.conf` file using `sudo nano ../../private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and change all occurrence of

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Also find this line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and uncomment it.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

My **.htaccess** in **/Project** directory. Not in **/application**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And edit your Codeigniter's project `config.php` file.
`Project/application/config/config.php` and set

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';
```

Because while running this project through System's Apache it'll throw an error of session directory. By default, its value is `NULL` so don't forget to edit it. Your `base_url` should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080';
```

You can use whatever port is free. This all must fix your **index.php** issue. 
Now configure your `Mysqli` db or whatever. You can use `localhost/phpmyadmin` for the DB but it'll make you dependent on Xampp. To overcome this, install **Mysql** library & **MysqlWorkbench** application. Start your mysql server using `mysql.server start`. Configure your `database.php` file and run your project using this command.

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Run this command into your project directory. And yes it's better to move out your project from `/htdocs` to some other directory. (Out of xampp)